# Need help linking to bundle on OS X

Tags: xcode, cocoa, macos, linker, bundle

I'm an experienced Java coder, but I'm new to XCode and C++, so sorry for the dumb question.

I'm writing some c++ code in XCode that needs to instantiate a Java Virtual Machine. There is a method in the OS X Java plugin called JavaVM_GetJNIEnv(), and a header file in the source code from Sun/Oracle called JavaVM.h with these lines:

```
// Gets the JNIEnv* associated with the Java VM, creating the JVM
// instance if necessary. Note that the implementation of this routine
// must be prepared for it to be called from more than one thread.
JNIEnv* JavaVM_GetJNIEnv();
```

I added the .h file to my XCode project, but I don't know how to link to the binary file. I figured out how to force-load in the linker, like this:

```
-force_load /System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin/Contents/MacOS/JavaPlugin2_NPAPI
```

(this file is a symbolic link; the real path is /System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin/Contents/Resources/Java/libplugin2_npapi.jnilib)

But then I get this error message:

```
ld: in /System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin/Contents/MacOS/JavaPlugin2_NPAPI, can't link with bundle (MH_BUNDLE) only dylibs (MH_DYLIB)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So my question is, how do I link to code in a .jnilib file with XCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. If you're trying to reference code stored in a .bundle, you don't actually link to it, you make calls to it at runtime and then reference the functions by name (ie. similar to Java's reflection, which I'm more familiar with).

```
NPError (*getEntryPoints)(NPPluginFuncs *aNPPFuncs); //Defines a variable which is a pointer to a function

CFURLRef bundleUrl = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL, CFSTR("/System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin"), kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, true);
CFBundleRef bundleRef = CFBundleCreate(NULL, bundleUrl);
getEntryPoints = (NPError (*)(NPPluginFuncs *))CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName ( bundleRef, CFSTR("NP_GetEntryPoints" ) ); //Sets the pointer function to a function loaded from the bundle

if( getEntryPoints == NULL ) {
    printf("getEntryPoints is NULL");
} else {
    NPPluginFuncs pluginFuncs;
    pluginFuncs.size = sizeof(NPPluginFuncs);

    NPError err = getEntryPoints( &pluginFuncs ); //This is what actually calls the library function
    //... do more stuff with plugin API ...
}
```

As an aside, this didn't wind up being very useful for my purposes because as far as I can tell, the java plugin API is only designed to be called from Mozilla-based browsers, and I'm trying to embed Java in my own application.

Answer (score 2):

You need to link to frameworks, not bundles.  Choose 'Add Existing Framework' and select JavaVM.framework, and Xcode should handle the rest!

Comment: I already have JavaVM.framework in my list of frameworks... maybe that function is defined in different library. I'll do some hunting with 'nm' to try to find out exactly which binary has the function that I'm looking for; maybe I just need to add a different framework.

Comment: OK, I found the real location of the file. I used 'nm' to verify that the function that I need is included. The location on the actual binary is '/System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin/Contents/MacOS/JavaPlugin2_NPAPI'. Since I can't add bundles to XCode, how would I link to this?

Comment: Under osx, the gcc wrapper accepts -F<dir> and -framework <Something.framework> as arguments. -F/-framework are analogously equivalent to to -L/-l, but I think sbooth is right - if it's not linking correctly something is wonky.

Comment: The stuff you're trying to link to is part of the Java plugin for web browsers (hence the NPAPI in the path). Are you sure that's what you want?