# How to re-export a dylib symbol from a dependent bundle

Tags: xcode, linker, dylib

Working with Xcode, I'm looking to re-export a symbol (a function specifically) from a mach-o bundle binary, where the symbol is originally defined in a dylib.

I've tried the -sub_library linker switch but that doesn't seem to re-export the dylib symbols, probably because I'm not building a dylib myself(?)

And the reexport-l / reexport_library switches seem to be unsupported in Xcode's linker.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for, if I understood you correctly. I'll be using libpthread as the hypothetical dylib containing functions you want to re-export.

**mybundle.c**:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void *foo(void *ctx) {
    puts((char *)ctx);
    return 0;
}
```

**mybundle.exp**:

```
_foo
_pthread_create
_pthread_join
```

Compile the bundle, dynamically linking to libpthread.dylib:

```
josh$ gcc -bundle -lpthread -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,mybundle.exp -o mybundle.so mybundle.c
```

**myloader.c**:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <pthread.h>    // merely for type definitions
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    void *(*foo)(void *ctx);
    /* the following cannot be declared globally without changing their names, 
       as they are already (and unnecessarily) declared in <pthread.h> */
    int (*pthread_create)(pthread_t *thrd, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*proc)(void *), void *arg);
    int (*pthread_join)(pthread_t thrd, void **val);

    void *bundle;
    assert(bundle = dlopen("mybundle.so", RTLD_NOW));
    assert(foo = dlsym(bundle, "foo"));
    assert(pthread_create = dlsym(bundle, "pthread_create"));
    assert(pthread_join = dlsym(bundle, "pthread_join"));

    pthread_t myThrd;
    pthread_create(&myThrd, 0, foo, "in another thread");
    pthread_join(myThrd, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile the loader:

```
josh$ gcc myloader.c -o myloader
```

Run:

```
josh$ ./myloader
in another thread
```

Observe that myloader is in no way linked to pthread, yet pthread functions are loaded and available at runtime through the bundle.

Comment: Thank jrodatus. I'm actually interested in exporting a symbol from my bundle which will directly point to an address in a dylib which it is linked with.

Comment: @Danra, AFAIK linking against a dylib, by definition, means that the dylib code is not actually contained in the bundle, only "dyld stub" functions that redirect at runtime are present. The addresses of any dylib functions, whether puts(), printf(), or pthread_create(), are indeterminate at compile-time, determined only by the dylinker at runtime. E.g., even the puts() call from foo() does not actually reference an address in a dylib, just the address of a stub function that invokes the dylinker to obtain whatever address puts() happens to have in the system at that runtime (see `otool -tV`).

Comment: @Danra, ...Therefore it seems to me the best you can ask for is to export (from the bundle) the local dyld stub address, which is what my code does (if I'm not mistaken). Running `nm` on any compiled binary will list linked-dylib-resident functions as "U" (undefined), as their code is NOT present at compile-time, and hence their symbol addresses are undetermined. Or maybe I'm just misunderstanding you?

Comment: Ok. Looks good. A couple of points: 1) Did you try linking myloader to the bundle statically and see if you can call the functions directly? I believe it should work the same, which is great and is what I was looking for. And 2) Are you sure you are getting the stubs addresses? Aren't you getting the actual addresses of where the functions exported by the dylib were mapped? (which is even better).  Aren't the undefined (until runtime) symbols just these actual addresses? With the stubs already fully functional and ready to call the addresses the symbols are mapped to.

Comment: 1) `ld: can't link with bundle (MH_BUNDLE) ...` See question/answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655548/need-help-linking-to-bundle-on-os-x. Also, I'm sure I read somewhere that it IS possible to statically link to a bundle on Linux, just not on OS X. 2) Hmm, that's an interesting thought I'll have to look into that. My understanding was that the *first call* to any stub rewrites the stub's first instruction to jump to the correct address. But maybe that behavior is variable. P.S. thanks for the upvote/bounty :)

Comment: @Danra, if you wanted to link to the bundle statically, is there any reason why you can't compile your bundle code as a dylib using `-dynamiclib` and link to that at compile-time? Since it's not a *static* link you still have to package the dylib with your executable, but you get the effect you wanted (i.e. you can access pthread functions directly without using dlopen &c, and without linking to libpthread). Don't have to answer that...just another idea.